# Azure publish annotations

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm not able to see my publish annotation in application insight metric explorer anymore. 
A Microsoft document state that they not available anymore!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/annotations

Did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft team and seems this feature is deprecated.

I found a nice way to add custom annotation by a PowerShell script:
[Deploy to Azure marks (Release Annotation) from desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090877/deploy-to-azure-marks-release-annotation-from-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you cannot see it in the **new metric explorer**, then the answer is yes.

But you can still see it from the **classic metric explorer**.

For more details, you can refer to this github issue: [annotations missing from Metrics blade](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17605).

Comment: Thanks but that page contains the same information.
I don't see metric classic any more. 
As "vhhughes" asked 
"Does that mean that this important feature is being retired? (i.e., not brought along to the new Metrics blade) Or does it mean it is being moved somewhere else? Or is it now accessible some other way?"
While Microsoft team answer was "We should have more information about the current metrics experience soon." almost 10 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the **Performance** blade in Application Insights? They should be visible in the chart there

Comment: No sir, nothing