# Deploy to Azure marks (Release Annotation) from desktop

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way to look for deployment event from Visual Studio in Azure? I would like to see when we deployed.
Previously, we had that option in Application Insight, now that they removed that feature I don't know where to look.

Comment: can you elloborate more on the question

Comment: Let's say that you deploy your app from Visual Studio to Azure. Is there any metric, flag, event, etc recorded on Azure so you can look into it?
The reason I need this is sometimes I see some bad performance, and I would like to know if that is after my last deployment or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would've expected to find that information, i.e., deployment/publish history in [Azure Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/platform-logs-overview) or [Deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=azure-portal) under the corresponding Resource group, but couldn't, and began digging further.

AFAIK, there isn't a straightforward way of tracking manual deployments on Azure. However, I can think of two workarounds:

- **Using VS Code:** When a deployment is manually performed using VS Code using the [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01) extension, it becomes easier to track the deployment history and also see the current/active version, along with various other configuration options and logs. For example:
  [image: Azure App Service extension for VS Code]
- **Using the KUDU console:** Browse to the deployments page within the Kudu console for your app service (would be of the form: *https://{app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments*), and you should see the history in JSON format. For example:
  [image: Deployment info from KUDU console]

**Note:** I'd strongly advise using the same mode of deployment always, for maintaining consistency, and also building a CI/CD Pipeline for streamlining your deployments if this is not a test environment or a PoC.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for something like DevOps Release annotations which can visible in the application insights charts.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, please check this extension out: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-appinsights.appinsightsreleaseannotations

Comment: Usage information available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/annotations

Comment: Yes I saw that, but AFAIK that is for devops. I looking for a solution while we deploy directly from VS. They had this feature but not anymore.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. However, if you feel that your requirement can benefit other Azure Users, please feel free to submit your suggestion in our Feedback Forum for Azure Application Insights (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights), and I'll be sure to upvote it too!

Comment: Btw, have you tried creating custom annotations from powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/annotations#create-custom-annotations-from-powershell ? This should let you create annotations from any process you like, even without using Azure DevOps.

Comment: Of course, do try and let me know if that works for you, and I can then update my answer to have that detail as well.

Comment: @Kamran Any luck with creating custom annotations? Let me know if you need further assistance here or please feel free to mark and close this if it helped. Thanks!